# How to display a field only when it changes when using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am running through a collection of quote records `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
    <h3>{{quote.chaptertitle}}</h3>
    <div>"{{quote.body}}"</div>
</div>
```

There are numerous quotes per chapter and of course I only want to display the chapter title the first time it appears as the records are displayed.

What is the best way to do this, e.g. create a hold variable in scope and then use `ng-if` to check it, or is there another easier way to do this with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I'm still unclear with your requirement. Would you please elaborate it? with example if possible?

Comment: is this what you need? `<h3 ng-if="$index == 0">{{quote.chaptertitle}}</h3>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed use `ng-if`:

```
<h3 ng-if="quote.chaptertitle != quotes[$index-1].chaptertitle">{{quote.chaptertitle}}</h3>
```

I personally would prefer to have a nested structure (chapter -> quote) in the first place. The existing grouping solutions suggested by others are nice, too.

Comment: Simple! I think your answer would suit best here ;) indeed, `quotes` should at least come sorted by `chaptertitle`

Comment: Very interesting, this works very well, I had thought along these lines but expected when $index was 0 that quotes[$index-1] would throw some kind of error, but apparently not.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Angular's parser / evaluator is forgiving. I think for the first item it resolves to `quote.chaptertitle != undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to group your quotes by `chaptertitle`

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in quotes | groupBy: 'chaptertitle'">
    <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="quote in value">
        "{{quote.body}}"
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:
`groupBy` filter comes from https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter, hosted here http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-filter

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ1DZRg1147EWUs4WEue)

Comment: You should mention where `groupBy` comes from, it's not part of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your quotes array so that if the title is the same then you set it to undefined instead:

```
var chapterTitle;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.quotes.length; i++) {
    var quote = $scope.quotes[i];
    if (quote.chaptertitle !== chapterTitle) {
      chapterTitle = quote.chaptertitle
    }
    else {
      quote.chaptertitle = undefined;
    }
}
```

And then in your view you can use `ng-if` on the h3:

```
<div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
  <h3 ng-if="quote.chaptertitle != undefined">{{quote.chaptertitle}}</h3>
  <div>"{{quote.body}}"</div>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJKEoSnp6Y3Wj4KBrAIi?p=preview)

But normally I would change my data structure (in the backend) so it would be something like this:

```
$scope.chapters = [
    {
        title: 'one',
        quotes: [
            {
                body: 'body1'
            },
            {
                body: 'body2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'two',
        quotes: [
            {
                body: 'body3'
            },
            {
                body: 'body4'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then you would use a nested repeat:

```
<div>
  <h3 ng-repeat-start="chapter in chapters">{{chapter.title}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="quote in chapter.quotes" ng-repeat-end>"{{quote.body}}"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of grouping the items as well, even though the post doesn't mention keeping the data intact for double binding for instance. If you want to group items, underscorejs has a neat groupBy function at http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy, so you could type `_.groupBy(quotes, function(n) { return n.chaptertitle; });` to get all groups of chapters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current index and compare to the previous record. Using your html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
         <h3 ng-hide="equalPrevious($index)">{{quote.chaptertitle}}</h3>
        <div>"{{quote.body}}"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.quotes = [
      { chaptertitle: 'Hello', body: '1' },
      { chaptertitle: 'Hello', body: '2' },
      { chaptertitle: 'Hello1', body: '3' }
    ];

    $scope.equalPrevious = function(index) {
        return index != 0 &&
            $scope.quotes[index].chaptertitle == $scope.quotes[index -1].chaptertitle;
    };
}
```

Will display the following result when run (and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ls2qoy0/))

Hello
"1"
"2"
Hello1
"3"